# Can a change in the routing table cause an ARP storm?

Tags: networking

I have an HTC EVO V with Android 4.1. While it doesn't lose the wifi signal, it periodically needs to be reset in order to make network connection. When I try to connect to Skype, for example, I might see the packet trace similar to this

```
20:09:06.516473 arp who-has 157.55.130.144 tell 192.168.0.68
20:09:06.547123 arp who-has 65.55.223.16 tell 192.168.0.68
20:09:06.826819 arp who-has 212.187.172.33 tell 192.168.0.68
20:09:07.006629 arp who-has 157.55.235.151 tell 192.168.0.68
20:09:07.036520 arp who-has 212.187.172.20 tell 192.168.0.68
20:09:07.166537 arp who-has 195.46.253.234 tell 192.168.0.68
20:09:07.546636 arp who-has 65.55.223.16 tell 192.168.0.68
20:09:07.697075 arp who-has 64.4.23.142 tell 192.168.0.68
20:09:07.836535 arp who-has 212.187.172.33 tell 192.168.0.68
20:09:08.006451 arp who-has 157.55.235.151 tell 192.168.0.68
...
```

I've never seen another network device exhibit this behavior, any ideas what could cause this? Even in this condition I can ping the device (192.168.0.68) from my firewall.

Comment: It's probably the only app that does this. Skype does some advanced network tricks (like [firewall hole punching](http://www.h-online.com/security/features/How-Skype-Co-get-round-firewalls-747197.html)) so I am not suprised by your question either

Comment: That's a very useful summary of how Skype attempts to set up the media channel. Still, I don't see how it could start a storm of spurrious arp requests for addresses that are _not locally connected_.